# Left join tables in sqlite ordered by desc limit

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, join, left-join

I want to left join two tables in sqlite. Short summary:

I have a table named "_Menu", one of the fields in this table is named "menu_id" with unique numbers.

Another table is called "_Approvals". This table has a history of which items has been "approved" or "unapproved". This table also has a field named "menu_id".

I want to get the lowest row (if there is any) from "_Approvals" for a given menu_id and join the two tables.

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT m.menu_id, m.p_id AS parent_id, m.name, m.url, a.status, a.auth
FROM _Menu AS m
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT * FROM _Approvals ORDER BY _Approvals.approval_id DESC LIMIT 1) as a
ON a.menu_id = m.menu_id
GROUP BY m.menu_id
ORDER BY m.menu_id
```

My problem is only the absolute last row in "_Approvals" gets joined. I.e I only know the status of the last item approved/unapproved.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want *the lowest row (if there is any) from "_Approvals" for a given menu_id* and not the *the lowest row from "_Approvals"* which is what your code does.
One way to do what you need is by using NOT EXISTS in the subquery that you join:

```
SELECT m.menu_id, m.p_id AS parent_id, m.name, m.url, a.status, a.auth
FROM _Menu AS m
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM _Approvals t
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM _Approvals
    WHERE menu_id = t.menu_id AND approval_id > t.approval_id
  )
) AS a
ON a.menu_id = m.menu_id
GROUP BY m.menu_id
ORDER BY m.menu_id
```

Another way with a [`CTE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT t.* FROM _Approvals t 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT menu_id, MAX(approval_id) 
    FROM _Approvals
    GROUP BY menu_id
  ) g
  ON g.menu_id = t.menu_id
)
SELECT m.menu_id, m.p_id AS parent_id, m.name, m.url, a.status, a.auth
FROM _Menu AS m LEFT JOIN cte AS a
ON a.menu_id = m.menu_id
GROUP BY m.menu_id
ORDER BY m.menu_id
```

Or with window function [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) if your version of **SQLite** is 3.25.0+:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY menu_id ORDER BY approval_id DESC) rn
  FROM _Approvals 
)
SELECT m.menu_id, m.p_id AS parent_id, m.name, m.url, a.status, a.auth
FROM _Menu AS m LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1
) AS a
ON a.menu_id = m.menu_id
GROUP BY m.menu_id
ORDER BY m.menu_id
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply!

The first and third code gives 1 for every "menu_id" present in the "_Approved"-table, even though some have their last row == 0.

The second code doesn't seem to work if the last entry for a.status == 0. But this works fine for my program. I just changed a bit in the rest of the code. Many thanks!

Comment: You said: *I want to get the lowest row (if there is any) from "_Approvals" for a given menu_id* Did you mean the last?

Comment: I highly appreciate you taking the time to do that!

Comment: All the MINs are now MAX and the < in the 1st query must be >. See my edited answer.

Comment: And ORDER BY approval_id **DESC** in the 3d query.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing this using `row_number()`:

```
SELECT m.menu_id, m.p_id AS parent_id, m.name, m.url,
       a.status, a.auth
FROM _Menu m LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT a.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.menu_id ORDER BY a.approval_id DESC) as seqnum
      FROM _Approvals a
     ) a
     ON a.menu_id = m.menu_id AND a.seqnum = 1
ORDER BY m.menu_id;
```

No aggregation should be needed for the query, assuming that `menu_id` is the primary key in `_Menu`.

If you are using an old version of SQLite that doesn't support window functions, then there are several options.  Probably the simplest is:

```
SELECT m.menu_id, m.p_id AS parent_id, m.name, m.url,
       a.status, a.auth
FROM _Menu m LEFT JOIN
     _Approvals a
     ON a.menu_id = m.menu_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT a.menu_id, MAX(a.approval_id) as max_approval_id
      FROM _Approvals a
      GROUP BY a.menu_id
     ) aa
     ON aa.menu_id = a.menu_id AND
        aa.max_approval_id = a.approval_id
ORDER BY m.menu_id;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the reply! I got the first code to work in sqlite DB Browser but in python I get the annoying "sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error"-Error.

When running the second code new rows are created for each "approval" i.e I get multiple rows with the same "menu_id". I just want the last one. Thanks again.

Comment: @Fred_Alb . . . You would only get duplicates with the second query if there are duplicates in `_Menu` or two rows with the same value in `_Approvals`.  I don't know what mistake you are making with the first query, but it would not return duplicates, unless in `_Menu`.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure either. There can me multiple rows in _Approvals with the same value, i.e. if an item is approved->unapproved->approved. Anywho, I picked one of the answers by forpas above. Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: @Fred_Alb . . . That is not an issue.  That is handled either by `row_number()` or by the `join`.  You should be eliminating the `GROUP BY`.  It is inefficient, it should not work (it violates the SQL standard), and it should be unnecessary.